# Learning TCL with sockets setting up echo server on local machine

Tags: tcl

I am new at TCL and trying an example within a book called *Practical Programming*.

I am trying to connect to an echo server with a client within the same file. So I have made a file called EchoServer.tclsh. I then have written the echo server code within this and the echoclient code. When I run this I receive an error that shows:

```
couldn't open socket: connection refused
    while executing
"socket $host $port"
    (procedure "Echo_Client" line 2)
    invoked from within
"Echo_Client localhost 2540"
    invoked from within
"set s [Echo_Client localhost 2540]"
    (file "echo_server.tcl" line 35)
```

The code for the server is:

```
proc Echo_server {port} {
        global echo
        set echo(main) {socket -server EchoAccept $port}
}
proc EchoAccept {sock addr port} {
        global echo
        puts "Accept $sock from $addr port $port"
        set echo(addr,$sock) [list $addr $port]
        f configure $sock -buffering line
        fileevent $sock readable [list Echo $sock]
}
proc Echo {sock} {
        global echo
        if {[eof $sock] || [catch {gets $sock line}]} {
                # end of file or abnormal connection drop
                 close $sock
                 puts "Close $echo(addr,$sock)"
                 unset echo(addr,$sock)
} else {
        if {[string compare $line "quit"] ==0} {
        # Prevent new connections. 
                # Existing connections stay open. 
        close $echo(main)
}
puts $sock $line
}
}
```

The code for the client is:

```
proc Echo_Client {host port} {
        set s [socket $host $port]
        fconfigure $s -buffering line
        return $s
}
set s [Echo_Client localhost 2540]
        puts $s "Hello!"
        gets $s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line

```
set echo(main) {socket -server EchoAccept $port}
```

should be

```
set echo(main) [socket -server EchoAccept $port]
```

And enter the event loop by doing a

```
vwait forever
```

at the end

Comment: Thanks this stops the error but looks like it just hangs now. Shouldn't this return a response to the clients request i.e puts $s Hello?

Comment: Only add the vwait to the server (it uses non-blocking IO). You should probably print the result of `gets $sock`, but do whatever you like.